# Location of pdf files in dspace server

Tags: pdf, dspace

I was wondering where in the live server files, can I find the pdf files I submitted in my DSpace instance? Does anyone knows where it is located? any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a handle and a bitstream id number, you can get to the path for your file with the following query.  By default your bitstream_id will be 1 unless you have added/removed bitstreams from your item.

```
select 
  '${YOUR_ASSETSTORE_PATH}' || 
  substring(bit.internal_id, 1, 2) || '/' || 
  substring(bit.internal_id, 3, 2) || '/' || 
  substring(bit.internal_id, 5, 2) || '/' || 
  bit.internal_id 
from bitstream bit 
inner join bundle2bitstream b2b on b2b.bitstream_id=bit.bitstream_id 
inner join bundle b on b.bundle_id=b2b.bundle_id and b.name='ORIGINAL' 
inner join item2bundle i2b on i2b.bundle_id=b.bundle_id 
inner join handle h on i2b.item_id=h.resource_id 
where h.handle='${handle}' and bit.sequence_id =${seq};
```

Comment: My bitstream links arent accessible by google docs viewer, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I recommend starting a new question tagged with dspace.  This is a few years old, but it might help.  https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Document+Preview+with+Google+Docs+viewer

Comment: I already tried everything that has been said there with no luck. I only get an iframe that does'nt load anything. but when I tried to use other pdf links , the iframe loads the document. Probably the bitstream links are wrong/not properly encoded or the documents are not publicly accessible by google. Either the two, I dont know how to implement and fix it.

Comment: I recommend that you start a new question that indicates that you are seeking help with the google docs viewer.

Comment: By "publicly accessible by google", IMO means that it should be in a production server, not in a test/local server (ie your dspace instance should be accessible by outside users via the internet).

Answer (score 1):

Within your DSpace installation directory, the default location for the storage of the uploaded assets is /assetstore

Within that directory, you can follow terry's advice for locating a particular file.