# DSpace find file path in assetstore

Tags: xml, xslt, repository, dspace

I need help, I want to find the location of a file by the handle given in the URL (e.g http://localhost:8080/xmlui/handle/123456789/5).
I'm using the xmlui theme and I don't know if is possible in the view item to get the location of the file (e.g /assestore/12/45/21/12452124442)

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081480/location-of-pdf-files-in-dspace-server/28084434

Answer (score 1):

This path is based on the internal ID of the item. In your example:
12452124442

```
First two characters = name of the first directory
Second series of two characters = name of the second directory
Third series of two characters = name of the third directory
```

The last part of the path is the internal id itself.

[Source of this information](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/storage/bitstore/BitstreamStorageManager.java#L92)